# Error for Next button in pywinauto using python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, automation, pywinauto

I have to currently install windows application, create a new database etc almost everyday when testing the Windows desktop software builds that I get.

To make this job easier, I've decided to use python with pywinauto to automate this process.

Currently I was just trying to write a sample script to automate just another application. Following is my code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start(r"E:\New\any-video-converter.exe -a -n -y --    arguments")
dlg=app['Setup - Any Video Converter Professional']
```

Now I wanted to click on the 'Next >' button on the setup so I added the following to my code:

```
app.dlg.Next.Click()
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 243, in
__resolve_control
    criteria)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 424, in
wait_until_passes
    raise err pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in
<module>
    app.dlg.NextButton.ClickInput()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 349, in
__getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 246, in
__resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 402, in
wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 188, in
__get_ctrl
    dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**criteria[0]))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line
84, in find_element
    elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 294, in
find_elements
    elements = findbestmatch.find_best_control_matches(best_match, wrapped_elems)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 534, in
find_best_control_matches
    raise MatchError(items = name_control_map.keys(), tofind = search_text)
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'dlg' in 'dict_keys([])'
```

Here is the snippet of the UI of the installer: [Sample installer UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otMEV.png)

I can't understand what's going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, here is the remaining part of the error message:

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 534, in find_best_control_matches
    raise MatchError(items = name_control_map.keys(), tofind = search_text)
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'dlg' in 'dict_keys([])'

Comment: It looks like that line should be `dlg.Next.Click()`, not `app.dlg.Next.Click()`.

Comment: @eryksun Similar error for dlg.Next.Click() ending with:

pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'Setup - Any Video Converter Professional' in 'dict_keys([])'

Comment: Which pywinauto version do you use? `print(pywinauto.__version__)` The latest 0.6.2 should show a bit different error message in similar case. Please edit your question with this additional info and updated traceback.